# Looking for a macro for ascending and descending command button with the ability to maintain the other corresponding rows of data

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

Have put together a macro to sort a column from ascending and descending order (posted below), But I am interested in a macro that can sort ascending to descending numerical order but keep the other rows of data corresponding with the ascending and descending data that has moved on my excel sheet. Anyone know the macro for this scenario?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


If CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Ascending" Then

'Sort ascending...
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A36"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:A36")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Decending"

Else

'sort decending
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A36") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A36")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Ascending"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the line `.SetRange Range("A1:A36")` should possibly include more columns, than just the A column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this line

```
.SetRange Range("A1:A36")
```

to this

```
.SetRange Range("A1:B36")
```

or change "B" to what ever column letter you go up to

Comment: Thank you very much